# Muldiv what is prod0 |= prod1 * twos?

Tags: solidity

In muldiv, what is this line of code doing?

```
prod0 |= prod1 * twos
```

Also can it overflow?

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/f213a10522a7bd808561c5a4b17266065a199dc7/contracts/utils/math/Math.sol#L185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bitwise operation They do not cause an overflow.

`prod0 |= prod1 * twos;` translated as `prod0 = prod0 | (prod1 * twos);`

The | operation is a binary OR. It puts a 1 on the result bit for which at least one of the corresponding operand bits is 1.

```
0 | 0 = 0
1 | 0 = 1
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 1 = 1
```

Then if you have incoming values:

```
prod0 = 2 // 00000010 binary
prod1 = 2
twos = 2
```

Then the result prod0 = prod0 | (prod1 * twos) is this:

```
(prod1 * twos) = 4 // 00000100 binary
prod0 = prod0 | 4 = 00000010 | 00000100 = 000000110 = 6
```

Comment: The syntax is clear, but what's the purpose of those instructions inside the multdiv? prod0 and prod1 are the high and low part of the 512 bits product, but what's the purpose of mixing them?

Comment: Consider this part in the source code of the entire function. The author comments on everything here: https://xn--2-umb.com/21/muldiv/